# PHP select statement not working?

Tags: php, database, select

For my login system, I'm trying to retrieve the user's information from a database based on the email. My code looks like this:

```
 session_start();
 require "database.php";
 $db = new Database("bills.db");

 $email = $_POST['email_address'];
 $password = $_POST['user_password'];

 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM billgroup WHERE (adminemail = :email)");
 $stmt->bindValue(':adminemail', $email, SQLITE3_TEXT);
 $users = $stmt->execute();
 $user = $users->fetchArray();
```

However whenever I run this, I cannot log in, and the $user array is always empty. Any help would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt->bindValue(':adminemail', $email, SQLITE3_TEXT);
```

Should be

```
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, SQLITE3_TEXT);
```

To match the defined variable in the query.